# How do I add IPA on top of words in Word

Tags: ms-word

I want to add IPA symbols above each word that I need to annotate.
The results should like this:
[image]

so how do I add all the symbols to the words that I want to add at once?if I already have the word list or data.

Comment: This is the wrong venue for this question - it's an end-user issue. Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. Please ask this kind of thing on a site such as Super User.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**

Open Microsoft Word. Select an IPA-compatible font, such as Lucida Sans Unicode or Arial Unicode MS from the font pull-down menu.

**Step 2**

Go to the "Insert" tab. Click the "Symbol" button and select "More Symbols."

Select "IPA Extensions" from the Subset drop-down menu. Choose the IPA symbol you want and click "Insert" to place the symbol in the document.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but what I want to do is automated typing instead of manually insert each symbol,so is it possible?